# iPhone 4S lock button

Tags: iphone

My lock button doesn't work and a couple of days ago my screen stopped working as well. I can't slide my lock screen or anything now; do I send it to service?

Comment: If you have an Apple store nearby go there. Otherwise go see your mobile provider.

Answer (score 1):

Reset your phone by holding down on the off button slide the red button to the right and your device should shut off wait for a few seconds take and hold down on your off button again until an Apple appears wait for a few more seconds and you should be able to work your phone. Good luck

Comment: If the lock button doesn't work how does holding the button help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you'll want someone that services the device to have a look. The buttons generally are not repairable, but get a quote from Apple and then decide what you wish to do as the screen sleep button is critical for the device operation.

Comment: Although not trivial, many Apple devices can be repaired by viewing guides from ifixit.com, and they also sell the hardware and tools to perform repairs on many devices. Buttons for iPhones are available on ifixit. But i think i understand your point, repairable, no. Replaceable, yes.